# Nome de propriedade dinâmica em Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, propriedade

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
var nomePropriedade = "Propriedade1";
var meuObjeto = {
    "nome" : "valor"
}
```

Gostaria que o **nome da propriedade** de **`meuObjeto`** recebesse o valor da variável **`nomePropriedade`**.

Assim, ao tentar acessar as propriedades de `meuObjeto` eu teria que fazer:

```
meuObjeto.Propriedade1
```

E o retorno seria: `"valor"`. Ou seja, seria o mesmo que:

```
var meuObjeto = {
    Propriedade1 : "valor"
}
```

É possível fazer isso?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Para criar uma propriedade com um nome dinamico como sugeres podes usar colchetes assim:

```
var nomePropriedade = "Propriedade1";
var meuObjeto = {
    "nome" : "valor"
}
meuObjeto[nomePropriedade] = 'foo';
```

Se quiseres atribuir o valor de nome será

```
meuObjeto[nomePropriedade] = meuObjeto.nome;
```

Se o que pretendes é **substituir** a propriedade `nome` então isso não dá, ou seja rename não dá. Tens de criar nova propriedade e fazer delete da anterior.

Neste caso de substituição deves fazer:

```
meuObjeto[nomePropriedade] = meuObjeto.nome;
delete meuObjeto.nome;
```

### Nota:

Na nova versão ECMAScript 6 (ECMAScript 2015) já é possivel defenir objetos com parâmetros dinâmicos no momento da criação do Objeto. Chama-se a isto [computed prope

Exemplo:

```
function foo() { return 1; }
var o = {
  [foo() + 1]: 'foo bar'
};
console.log(o); // dá: Object {2: "foo bar"}
```

Answer (score 4):

Se pretende apenas criar e acessar propriedades variáveis, ou seja, criar e acessar propriedades de um objeto dinamicamente, basta usar os braquetes:

```
var a = 'foo'; 
var b = 'bar';

var myObj = new Object;
myObj[a] = b;

console.log( myObj[a], myObj.foo );
```

Answer (score 4):

Como complemento das respostas anteriores, também é possível verificar, dinamicamente, se a propriedade foi definida, da seguinte forma

```
var nomePropriedade = "Propriedade1";
var meuObjeto = {
    "nome" : "valor"
}

if (meuObjeto.hasOwnProperty(nomePropriedade)) {
    // Sim, possui a propriedade
}
```

Comment: Wallace, só gostaria de fazer uma resalva, `hasOwnProperty` vai retornar falso caso a propriedade exista no prototipo e não no objeto, neste caso um `typeof meuObjeto[nomePropriedade] !== 'undefined'` funcionaria, certo que duvido que o AP vá precisar usar Contrutores e Prototipos. Você pode ver o que estou apontando neste fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6nxmvsLx/