# Como transformar o valor de uma variável no nome da propriedade de um objeto?

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho esse exemplo de código:

```
var a = 'foo';
var b = {a:'2'};
b.foo //undefined
```

o que eu desejo é que b.foo exista e retorne "2" nesse exemplo, mas ao criar a variável "b" a variável "a" deixa de existir quando chamada dentro do objeto o que ocorre é que o nome da propriedade se torna "a"... como fazer para o nome da propriedade ser o valor de uma variável já existente?

Comment: Esse código não faz nenhum sentido. Demonstre melhor o que deseja pra gente ver uma forma viável de resolver o que realmente precisa.

Comment: Você quer que o valor da variavel seja o nome do atributo do objeto ? tipo isso ? https://jsfiddle.net/filadown/whx4tctz/

Comment: Acho que ele quer algo do tipo: `b['foo'] = '2';`

Comment: Aqui tb tem uma resposta boa: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/82668/14674

Comment: Pessoal, obrigado pela ajuda. A dúvida era realmente simples, bastava usar b[a] = '2' =)! estou tirando a ferrugem do Js aos poucos aqui, obrigado!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se entendi bem, você quer criar o atributo no objeto `b` que está no valor de `a`. Então podes fazer assim:

```js
var a = 'foo';
var b = {};
b[a] = '2';

document.getElementById('saida').innerHTML = 'b.foo = ' + b.foo;
```

```html
<p id='saida'></p>
```

Nessa resposta há mais detalhes: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/82668/14674

Answer (score 3):

ES6 introduz nomes de propriedade computadorizada, que permitem que você faça:

```js
var a = 'foo';

var b = {[a]: 2};

console.log(b);
```

Referencia: [Developer Mozilla - Object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)