# Como adicionar um objeto em um array dentro de outro objeto

Tags: javascript, json

Tenho o seguinte função que cria um objeto:

```
function createDebit(name, value, paymentDate){
    var debit = {"type": name,"value": value,"PaymentDate": paymentDate};
    return debit;
}
```

Esse objeto que ela retorna eu vou add. em outro objeto com essa função:

```
var newDebit = createDebit("GVT", "200.00", "10/10/2010");
addValue("Bradesco", "arrayDebits", newDebit);

function addValue(where, element, content){
    var execute;
    var local = localStorage.getItem(where);
    local = JSON.parse(local);
    var verifyType = "$.isArray(local."+element+")";
    // Verifica se o elemento do objeto destino é um array
    if(eval(verifyType)){
        // Caso seja, add o conteudo via push
        if(typeof(content) == "string"){
            execute = "local."+element+".push('"+content+"')";
        }else if(typeof(content) == "object"){
            execute = "local."+element+".push("+content+")";
        }
    }else{
        execute = "local."+element+"='"+content+"'";
    }
    console.log(execute);
    console.log("Execute now...");
    eval(execute);
    console.log("Done Execute");
    storage_save(where, local);
}
```

Porem sempre dá erro:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: Unexpected identifier SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Caso eu tente passar via STRING o objeto:

```
function createDebit(name, value, paymentDate){
    var debit = '{"type":' + name + ',"value": ' + value + ',"PaymentDate": ' + paymentDate + '}';
    return debit;
}
```

Não dá erro, porem quando vou ler o JSON transformando ele em STRING, vejo que na realidade já não é mais um objeto, mais sim uma STRING:

> {"nameCategory":"Bradesco","arrayDebits":["{\"type\": \"GVT\",\"value\": value,\"PaymentDate\": paymentDate}"]}

Como posso salvar de fato o objeto dentro do array que está dentro de outro objeto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Não uses o `eval` para este caso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4154/129), ele é perigoso. O `localStorage` é util mas não é de confiar, e usar *strings* do `localStorage` no eval é má prática.

Podes fazer assim, nota como uso `[]` para [aceder a propriedades de objetos dinamicamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82664/129):

```js
function createDebit(name, value, paymentDate) {
  return {
    "type": name,
    "value": value,
    "PaymentDate": paymentDate
  };
}

function addValue(where, element, content) {
  var local = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(where));
  if (!local[element]) local[element] = content;
  else local[element].push(content);
  console.log("Done!");
  storage_save(where, local);
}

var newDebit = createDebit("GVT", "200.00", "10/10/2010");
addValue("Bradesco", "arrayDebits", newDebit);
```

Comment: 1 - Vi que o  if (!local[element]) devolve true ou false, mais o que exatamente ele faz? 2 - O resultado ainda dá: `{"nameCategory":"Bradesco","arrayDebits":["{\"type\":GVT,\"value\": 200.00,\"PaymentDate\": 10/10/2010}"]}` Porem estou achando que é por causa do metodo `function storage_save(name, json){
 var stringJSON = JSON.stringify(json);
 localStorage.setItem(name, stringJSON);
}` porem se eu não fizer assim, ele não permite o setItem.

Comment: @CarlosM `1:` é uma maneira de saber se `local. arrayDebits` já está defenido ou não. Se fôr vazio recebe o valor de `content` diretamente. `2:` isso pode ser por causa de valores antigos que tens no `localStorage`. Apaga esses valores e "começa de novo". Tens de usar `JSON.stringify` mesmo, o localStorage só aceita strings.

Comment: 1 - Intendi! 2 - verdade! Funcionou certinho.